# SLsvcUtil.exe proxy generated class does not inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, web-services, silverlight-3.0

I been getting a really nasty error when updating a "Service Reference" for a WCF web service when using VisualStudio 2010 Beta 2 so I have switched to using SLsvcUtil.exe to generate the client proxy to use in my Silverlight 3 application.

Problem is that I noted that before, when using "Add Service Reference" from within Visual Studio, generated classes would inherit from System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged while the ones generated by SLSvcUtil.exe do not. Apart from this difference, I like this approach over the Visual Studio "Add Service Reference dialog.

The question is: Am I missing a flag or something when running the command line tool? or better still..is this approach to generating proxy is good? I watched an episode of dnrtV (show #122) where Miguel Castro shows a totally different approach in creating the proxies. While I really like his approach, I'm working with a legacy application that at the moment we don't have time to convert to.

Thanks and I really appreciate your comments on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the SL version much, but have you tried adding `/edb` or `/enableDataBinding` to your command? (like with `svcutil.exe`)? This option is [shown on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470117(VS.95).aspx), so I expect it'll work.

Comment: Worked wonderfully! I'm a bit embarrassed I missed that on MSDN! must have been another case of 3 o'clockitis! 

Thanks Marc. Appreciated.